# String manipulation in Makefile

Tags: makefile, substr

I am trying to manipulate a string in my MAKEFILE, which is captured in a variable. I am not very familiar with MAKEFILE and i'm not a developer!

The string is an output of my subnets from an AWS acount:

`"subnet-013e3be0be24cb26d, subnet-067b5d1d322c7e1f0, subnet-02a2cc16c6b258d35"`

However, i need my string to represent:

`"subnet-013e3be0be24cb26d", "subnet-067b5d1d322c7e1f0", "subnet-02a2cc16c6b258d35"`

so that the quotation marks are in this format.

I have looked at the substr documentation, but i can't find the solution to how i can achieve this.

Can anyone provide any insight please? Much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask] and [edit] the question with a bit more information, such as: a variable in what language? Please do add the tag of the language you're working in, that way people familiar with that language will be able to find your question.

Comment: So far i have forgotten:

```"subnet-013e3be0be24cb26d, "subnet-067b5d1d322c7e1f0, "subnet-02a2cc16c6b258d35```

By running the following code:

```echo $(subst subnet,\"subnet,"subnet-013e3be0be24cb26d, subnet-067b5d1d322c7e1f0, subnet-02a2cc16c6b258d35")```

Comment: You should be able to replace `,` with `","`, assuming the spaces are not significant. May need to put the comma in a variable to distinguish it from parameter separator in the command itself.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if you provided an actual example.  But if you're using GNU make you can use the `subst` function, but you have to hide special characters like `,` inside a variable:

```
FOO := "subnet-013e3be0be24cb26d, subnet-067b5d1d322c7e1f0, subnet-02a2cc16c6b258d35"

COMMA := ,
BAR := $(subst $(COMMA) ,"$(COMMA) ",$(FOO))
```